# Is there an easy way to extract rows from pandas DataFrame from a boolean expression?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I'm currently struggling trying to extract rows from a DataFrame using vectorization. I'm pretty sure there's an easy way, expression or function to achieve this, but I couldn't find it.
I have this dataframe (from a mysql database):

```py
             date_taux    taux  taux_min  taux_max
0  2021-02-15 13:55:00  2.1166    2.1155    2.1232
1  2021-02-15 14:00:00  2.1256    2.1166    2.1300
2  2021-02-15 14:05:00  2.1312    2.1206    2.1348
3  2021-02-15 14:10:00  2.1174    2.1166    2.1416
4  2021-02-15 14:15:00  2.1103    2.1060    2.1253
5  2021-02-15 14:20:00  2.1269    2.1143    2.1277
6  2021-02-15 14:25:00  2.1239    2.1115    2.1300
7  2021-02-15 14:30:00  2.0880    2.0879    2.1299
8  2021-02-15 14:35:00  2.0827    2.0827    2.1060
9  2021-02-15 14:40:00  2.0747    2.0718    2.0996
10 2021-02-15 14:45:00  2.0846    2.0779    2.0861
11 2021-02-15 14:50:00  2.0826    2.0806    2.0894
12 2021-02-15 14:55:00  2.0350    2.0350    2.0857
13 2021-02-15 15:00:00  2.0796    2.0350    2.0797
14 2021-02-15 15:05:00  2.0717    2.0587    2.0800
15 2021-02-15 15:10:00  2.0762    2.0705    2.0819
16 2021-02-15 15:15:00  2.0793    2.0650    2.0884
17 2021-02-15 15:20:00  2.1005    2.0831    2.1064
18 2021-02-15 15:25:00  2.1164    2.1017    2.1206
19 2021-02-15 15:30:00  2.1199    2.1176    2.1300
```

And I also have this numpy array:

```py
[2.         2.01694915 2.03389831 2.05084746 2.06779661 2.08474576
 2.10169492 2.11864407 2.13559322 2.15254237 2.16949153 2.18644068
 2.20338983 2.22033898 2.23728814 2.25423729 2.27118644 2.28813559
 2.30508475 2.3220339  2.33898305 2.3559322  2.37288136 2.38983051
 2.40677966 2.42372881 2.44067797 2.45762712 2.47457627 2.49152542
 2.50847458 2.52542373 2.54237288 2.55932203 2.57627119 2.59322034
 2.61016949 2.62711864 2.6440678  2.66101695 2.6779661  2.69491525
 2.71186441 2.72881356 2.74576271 2.76271186 2.77966102 2.79661017
 2.81355932 2.83050847 2.84745763 2.86440678 2.88135593 2.89830508
 2.91525424 2.93220339 2.94915254 2.96610169 2.98305085 3.        ]
```

My goal is to add a column to the dataframe, with the amount of numbers in the array between `taux_min` and `taux_max`. An expected result would be:

```py
             date_taux    taux  taux_min  taux_max amount_lines
0  2021-02-15 13:55:00  2.1166    2.1155    2.1232            1
1  2021-02-15 14:00:00  2.1256    2.1166    2.1300            1
2  2021-02-15 14:05:00  2.1312    2.1206    2.1348            0
3  2021-02-15 14:10:00  2.1174    2.1166    2.1416            2
4  2021-02-15 14:15:00  2.1103    2.1060    2.1253            1
5  2021-02-15 14:20:00  2.1269    2.1143    2.1277            1
6  2021-02-15 14:25:00  2.1239    2.1115    2.1300            1
7  2021-02-15 14:30:00  2.0880    2.0879    2.1299            2
8  2021-02-15 14:35:00  2.0827    2.0827    2.1060            2
9  2021-02-15 14:40:00  2.0747    2.0718    2.0996            1
10 2021-02-15 14:45:00  2.0846    2.0779    2.0861            1
...
```

I tried using this code:

```py
sql = dbm.MySQL()
data = sql.pdselect("SELECT date_taux, taux, taux_min, taux_max FROM binance_rates_grid WHERE action = %s AND date_taux > %s ORDER BY date_taux ASC", "TOMOUSDT", datetime.utcnow()-timedelta(days=11))
print(data)

print("==================")
grids = np.linspace(2, 4, 60)

data["lignes"] = len(grids[(data["taux_min"] < grids) & (data["taux_max"] < grids)])

print(data)
```

But I fairly get this error: `ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (2868,), (60,))`

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here, but I cannot tell what.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `numpy` broadcasting:

```
x, y = df[['taux_min', 'taux_max']].values.T
mask = (x[:, None] <= arr) & (arr <= y[:, None])
df['amount_lines'] = mask.sum(1)
```

---

```
              date_taux    taux  taux_min  taux_max  amount_lines
0   2021-02-15 13:55:00  2.1166    2.1155    2.1232             1
1   2021-02-15 14:00:00  2.1256    2.1166    2.1300             1
2   2021-02-15 14:05:00  2.1312    2.1206    2.1348             0
3   2021-02-15 14:10:00  2.1174    2.1166    2.1416             2
4   2021-02-15 14:15:00  2.1103    2.1060    2.1253             1
5   2021-02-15 14:20:00  2.1269    2.1143    2.1277             1
6   2021-02-15 14:25:00  2.1239    2.1115    2.1300             1
7   2021-02-15 14:30:00  2.0880    2.0879    2.1299             2
8   2021-02-15 14:35:00  2.0827    2.0827    2.1060             2
9   2021-02-15 14:40:00  2.0747    2.0718    2.0996             1
10  2021-02-15 14:45:00  2.0846    2.0779    2.0861             1
11  2021-02-15 14:50:00  2.0826    2.0806    2.0894             1
12  2021-02-15 14:55:00  2.0350    2.0350    2.0857             3
13  2021-02-15 15:00:00  2.0796    2.0350    2.0797             2
14  2021-02-15 15:05:00  2.0717    2.0587    2.0800             1
15  2021-02-15 15:10:00  2.0762    2.0705    2.0819             0
16  2021-02-15 15:15:00  2.0793    2.0650    2.0884             2
17  2021-02-15 15:20:00  2.1005    2.0831    2.1064             2
18  2021-02-15 15:25:00  2.1164    2.1017    2.1206             1
19  2021-02-15 15:30:00  2.1199    2.1176    2.1300             1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `apply` with `lambda` to go through the array:

```
df['amount_lines'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(np.logical_and(arr >= x['taux_min'], arr <= x['taux_max'])),axis=1)
```

Where `grids` is the numpy array.

In a brief example:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,4,52,10],'B':[3,5,6,100,13]})
df.apply(lambda x: sum(np.logical_and(arr >= x['A'], arr <= x['B'])),axis=1)
```

Outputs

```
0    3
1    4
2    3
3    0
4    0
```